# unzip archive with filenames containing umlaut

Tags: macos, filesystem, zip

I got a `zip` archive containing files some of which with a name containing German umlaute, such as ö. The `unzip` command on a terminal fails to create such files, complaining about an illegal byte sequence.

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Have you tried simple double-click, or a 3rd party app such as [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) (donationware, free direct download or paid from App Store) or 
[BetterZip](https://macitbetter.com) (paid)

Comment: Info-zip has documented issues with utf-8, so it's entirely possible that this particular file is confusing it.  ref https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Info-ZIP#Official_betas and https://sourceforge.net/p/infozip/support-requests/10/

Answer (score 5):

When `zip` fails with:

```
Archive:  archive.zip
error:  cannot create filename?.txt
    Illegal byte sequence
```

either use:

- the Archive Utility app:

  ```
  open <path to zip file>
  ```
- or the `ditto` command, which has proven to be more resilient than `zip` when uncompressing files with Unicode characters in their names:

  1. Launch Terminal.
  2. Run:

     `ditto -V -x -k <path to zip file> <destination folder>`

     where:

     `<path to zip file>` is the full or relative path to your zip file

     `<destination folder>` is the folder that will contain the uncompressed files

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following command:

```
touch ö && zip -R ö.zip ö && rm ö && unzip ö.zip
```

It doesn't complain here. You have to specify your problem a bit further, or to upload the archive somewhere.

Did some googling, the problem is related to Zip's encoding.
Two possible solutions:

1. Use open, as in open fileWithUnicodeCharacters.zip. It looks like open will call an internal OS X program that has no problem open these type of .zip files.
2. Replacing unzip utility used in our script with ditto